# JPA - Spring Boot - password encoding

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to JPA and Spring Boot.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt

I'm looking to encode the password -- where would I place this bean -- do I just define it in my application.properties or in the pom.xml

Comment: Your bean can be in your spring securrity class

Comment: -- cheers - I've added the bean and the encoding - but when I refreshed the page I get hit with a login/password box - but I don't have any details - what do I do now?

Comment: I bypassed it with "security.basic.enabled=false" in my application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Also you can define in your @Configuration beans, but is recommend to define password encoder in your @@EnableWebSecurity beans, it is automatically add @Configuration annotation for you and you can config more security related things.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class YourWebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: -- cheers - I've added the bean and the encoding - but when I refreshed the page I get hit with a login/password box - but I don't have any details - what do I do now?

Comment: I bypassed it with "security.basic.enabled=false" in my application.properties